# What was Shankara's stand on Bhairava Agamas?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, shaivism, agamas, kashmiri-shaivism

It is a well-known fact that Shankara rejected both Vaishnava and Shaivite Agamas. However, I got to know from a friend that the philosophy of  Bhairava Agamas were similar to Shankara's Advaita Vedanta philosophy. Did Shankara reject all Shaivite Agamas including the Bhairava ones?

Comment: Do you only want the views of Adi Shankaracharya or the views of Advaita Acharyas in general?  Kashmiri Shaivism, which is based on the Bhairava Tantras, is discussed as a rival school in Vidyaranya's Sarva Darshana Sangraha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Only Shankara's views.

Comment: He criticized pashupata and kapalika if i am.not wrong..not every shaivagamas. Are you sure about it ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Sure about what?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury sure that he condemned all.agamas ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I am not sure. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Although Kashmira Shaivism is a type of advaitavada, there are many differences between it and advaita vedanta. Prof. Chandradhar Sharma has a detailed discussion on these differences in his book "The Advaita Tradition in Indian Philosophy: A Study in Buddhism, Vedanta and Kashmira Shaivism". The author has detailed knowledge of Sankara and quotes him profusely, but in the extensive discussion about the differences between Advaita and Kashmira, he offers nothing from Sankara. Most of the major commentators on Kashmira lived after Sankara.

Comment: if you're interested in the differences between advaita and kashmira, edit your question without Sankara and it can be answered.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Maybe I will ask a different question on that.

Comment: It seems he was much unaware of Bhairavhood. Remember, KS was very secret  until Islamic invasion of Kashmir. Kashmiri AchAryas felt the need of writing just to preserve teachings against upcoming Islamic fundamentalism.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I am not so sure if he fully rejected Vaishnava agamas. My understanding is he accepted certain parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, Adi Shankaracharya was opposed to the Bhairava Tantras.** Adi Shankaracharya sent his shishyas to defeat the followers of the Bhairava Tantras, as described in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/QWcS) from the Madhaviya Shankara Digvijaya:

> Now Acharya Shankara, along with the king Sudhanva and a large number of disciples, started on a Dig-vijaya - a missionary tour for the propagation of the Advaita doctrine by controverting all philosophies opposed to it.... Next, blessing the people of Andhra country and worshiping Lord Venkatanatha, he reached the land of Vidarbha. He was given a cordial reception by the king of that place.  There, Padmapada and other disciples engaged themselves in **controverting the perverse doctrines of the Bhairavas**.